# How do I know that this function has completed and returned something? angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I call this function in the component

```
this.contactsService.loadChat(chatListItem);
```

How do I know that this function has completed and returned something?
here are the insides

```
 loadChat(chatListItem: ListItem) {
    this.whatsappApiService
      .getMessages(chatListItem.contactId, 1, 25)
      .subscribe((loadedMessages: Message[]) => {
        this.whatsappContactsFacade.loadedChats(loadedMessages);
        this.loadedSubject.next(true);
      });
  }
```

Comment: inside subscribe add last statement that some variable will become true , so that you can detect that function execution is in last step.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a callback function when the function is done the callback will get called, the code for this will look something like this

```
this.contactsService.loadChat(chatListItem, () => {alert("i'm a callback function")});
```

```
 loadChat(chatListItem: ListItem, callback) {
    this.whatsappApiService
      .getMessages(chatListItem.contactId, 1, 25)
      .subscribe((loadedMessages: Message[]) => {
        this.whatsappContactsFacade.loadedChats(loadedMessages);
        this.loadedSubject.next(true);
        callback() // callback gets called here
      });
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest to debug this rxjs subscription is better then adding callback function and unnecessary code

Answer (score 0):

Just like Sarkar said just before, you can use callbacks.

You can either use the simple way as he said but you can also modulate the message sent depending of if it's an error or the appropriate behavior.

For example, if whatsappApiService.getMessages() can't return an observable, it will trigger an error that will be displayed in a dedicated alert.

```js
this.contactsService.loadChat(chatListItem, (msg) => {alert(msg)});

loadChat(chatListItem: ListItem, callback) {
    this.whatsappApiService
      .getMessages(chatListItem.contactId, 1, 25)
      .subscribe((loadedMessages: Message[]) => {
        this.whatsappContactsFacade.loadedChats(loadedMessages);
        this.loadedSubject.next(true);
        callback() // callback gets called here
      })
    .then(() => {
        //Behavior if everything is fine
        this.msg = "It's all good";
    })
    .error((err) => {
        //Behavior if there is a problem
        this.msg = "Error : " + err;
    });
}
```